# C# Unable to cast object of type system int64 to type system string

Tags: c#

```
 Dictionary<string, object> featureProperties = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(properties);
            
 gJFeature.id = int.Parse((string)featureProperties["OBJECTID"]);
```

**id= integer type**

> Unable to convert object to interger.

Can any one help me find out the solution.

Comment: is it not convertible to `int64` or `string`? one suggestion just check for `null` value

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. 
Your question isn't very clear - the title says one thing and the text says another. Also, your code isn't properly formatted. 
Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

We can conclude that `featureProperties["OBJECTID"]` is not a `string`, but a `long` (aka `Int64`).

Consider instead:

```
gJFeature.id = Convert.ToInt32(featureProperties["OBJECTID"]);
```

which handles a broad range of possible values.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this :

```
 Dictionary<string, object> featureProperties = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(properties);
            
 gJFeature.id =Convert.ToString(featureProperties["OBJECTID"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `object` is boxed `Int64 (long)`.
You cannot cast `long` to `string`. You need to convert it via `ToString()`.

`gJFeature.id = int.Parse(featureProperties["OBJECTID"].ToString());`

Or if you can first unbox your `long` and then cast it to `int`:

`gJFeature.id = (int)(long)featureProperties["OBJECTID"];`